# Android Navigation DeepLinks - How can I distinguish between navigating with navigation actions vs deep links

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, deep-linking

I have navigation actions and a deeplink that takes you to a certain fragment depending on where you navigate from , I want to determine if deeplink was used or just navigation actions .

Answer (score 4):

This is precisely what the [`KEY_DEEP_LINK_INTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#KEY_DEEP_LINK_INTENT) extra is for: if it is present in your fragment's arguments, then you have been launched via a deep link.

```
bool launchedFromDeepLink = getArguments() != null &&
    getArguments().containsKey(NavController.KEY_DEEP_LINK_INTENT)
```

Comment: Thank you kindly , but where do I add the Argument , currently my navigation code for the fragment looks like so ...

Comment: <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_details"
        android:name="DetailsFragment"
        android:label="details">
        <deepLink
            android:id="@+id/deepLink"
            app:uri="app://videos/{videoId}" />
        <argument
            android:name="videoId"
            app:argType="integer" />
    </fragment>

Comment: You do not need to add any arguments at all. This is done automatically for you, completely independent of any arguments.

Comment: It is returning false each time , i'll look into it thank you .